# Ensure text remains visible during webfont load not getting resolved in Google pagespeed insights

Tags: google-pagespeed

Ensure text remains visible during webfont load issue is not getting resolved in google pagespeed insights report even after adding `font-display: fallback` to the CSS.

How can I resolve the issue?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Jura;
  src: url(../fonts/Jura-Regular.eot);
  src: url(../fonts/Jura-Regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(../fonts/Jura-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'), url(../fonts/Jura-Regular.woff) format('woff'), url(../fonts/Jura-Regular.ttf) format('truetype'), url(../fonts/Jura-Regular.svg#svgFontName) format('svg');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: fallback;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I got rid of it by adding font-display: swap;

```
@font-face{
    font-family:FontAwesome;
    font-display: swap;
    src:url(fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0);
}
```

Comment: While `font-face` can be used for normal fonts, it is not a good idea to use it for icon fonts. In reality, `swap` uses a fallback font to display while waiting for the real font to download, then it just "swaps" to the real font. This said, font awesome doesn't have a fallback, so it will either display a weird character or something else depending on the browser. You can check a really nice answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49461308/correct-font-display-value-for-icon-fonts

You cannot easily bypass this, so be careful when using icon fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding the **@fontface** rule directly between  tags in  index.html.
You can also try setting the font-display at the top of the **@fontface** rule.

```
font-display: fallback;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
src: local('Montserrat'), url('https://fonts.googleapis.com  /css?family=Montserrat:300,700') format('woff2');
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
```

Comment: it's a Lighthouse / Pagespeed issue or it's working the same way into browsers?

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved by adding an online JS library of the font-awesome between head tag on website.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/configuration#configuration

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            FontAwesomeConfig = {searchPseudoElements: true}
        </script>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/js/all.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```