# Google Pagespeed ensure text remains visible during webfont load in fon Awsome

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Google pagespeed Insight recommends me to "Ensure text remains visible during webfont load".

here is the font awesome url fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0 causing the problem

Below code is what CSS looks like

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}
```

How do I resolve that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ensure text remains visible during webfont load not getting resolved in Google pagespeed insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277912/ensure-text-remains-visible-during-webfont-load-not-getting-resolved-in-google-p)